# Replacing windshield with Mexican auto permit

Tags: automobiles, us-citizens, mexico

When you drive from the U.S. into Mexico (past the free-trade zone) you are required to obtain a foreign vehicle permit, which is affixed to the windshield (with a receipt portion to be kept in the vehicle).

What happens if you have to replace the windshield while in Mexico?  Must a new permit be acquired, or will the receipt portion be sufficient in case of a traffic stop, and to receive the cash deposit when leaving the country again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the permit from the windshield, which **needs to be turned in**, and carry it with you. Customs wants it back to refund the deposit and they will not let you get a new permit if you have not turned in an old one.

If the car is involved in a accident and is a total loss it is best to remove the permit from the windshield. If the car is stolen the insurance company needs to provide you with a letter that the car is gone, stolen, or totaled, and provide that letter to customs with claim information ... to get the deposit back; And, to allow you to get permits in the future.

This comes from the claims department of [Instant Mexico Auto Insurance](http://www.instant-mex-auto-insur.com/)